# Revolut merchant API, sandbox PAYMENT FAILED

Tags: api, payment, checkout

I'm trying to implement the RevolutCheckout.js

It worked at the beginning until suddenly it just stopped working and getting the 500 error after inserting card details, all the time.

I've copied exact code from documentation:

```
RevolutCheckout('generated_public_id', 'sandbox').then(function (RC) {
        RC.payWithPopup({
            name: "First Last",
            email: "customer@example.com",
            billingAddress: {
                countryCode: "UK",
                region: "Greater London",
                city: "London",
                streetLine1: "Revolut",
                streetLine2: "1 Canada Square",
                postcode: "EC2V 6DN"
            },
            onSuccess() {
                window.alert("Thank you!");
            },
            onError(message) {
                window.alert("Oh no :(");
            },
            onCancel() {
                window.alert("Payment cancelled!")
            },
        })
    });
```

[The error I get every time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVStq.png)

I changed nothing, it worked before.